# Custom Gitbook Themes

Tags: css, themes, gitbook

Does anyone know how to modify the look of a git book? I've seen 2 books that have a different look from the default:
http://codac.co/
http://coalman.github.io/tott-gulpjs/book/

But can someone point me in the right direction of how to customize the look and/or build a custom theme for gitbook?

I can't seem to find any documentation on customizing a gitbook.

Comment: The makers of gitbook answered my question on twitter: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gitbook-plugin-wabtheme

Comment: good question, but that plugin above is plugin-sample code with sample readme and just has custom theme in its name set.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the CLI Toolchain (as opposed to the online editor noted above), you need to create a directory called '/styles' in the root of your book then add a 'website.css' file to that directory.

Customize that website.css file to adjust the style of your gitbook.

'gitbook serve' or 'gitbook build' when done to view changes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are editing your gitbook online at gitbook.com, you can edit the stylesheets by selecting the down arrow in the far right of the toolbar: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can start to see the theme templates and change too see how it works

gitbook / theme /

gitbook / theme / stylesheets /